# Run multiple functions every second, write result to file

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to run three functions (each can take up to 1 second to execute) every second. I'd then like to store the output from each function, and write them to separate files.

At the moment I'm using `Timer`s for my delay handling. (I could subclass `Thread`, but that's getting a bit complicated for this simple script)

```
def main:
    for i in range(3):
        set_up_function(i)
        t = Timer(1, run_function, [i])
        t.start()
    time.sleep(100) # Without this, main thread exits

def run_function(i):
    t = Timer(1, run_function, [i])
    t.start()
    print function_with_delay(i)
```

What's the best way to handle the output from function_with_delay? Append the result to a global list for each function?

Then I could put something like this at the end of my main function:

```
...
while True:
    time.sleep(30) # or in a try/except with a loop of 1 second sleeps so I can interrupt
    for i in range(3):
        save_to_disk(data[i])
```

Thoughts?

---

Edit: Added my own answer as a possibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the python [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module is designed for precisely this sort of scenario. You could do something like this, for example:

```
def main():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Timer(1, run_function, [q, i])
        t.start()

    while True:
        item = q.get()
        save_to_disk(item)
        q.task_done()

def run_function(q, i):
    t = threading.Timer(1, run_function, [q, i])
    t.start()
    q.put(function_with_delay(i))
```

Comment: +1 This works because the output is to separate files. If it was non-trivial and involved a combination of outputs then you would have to wait for all of the queued items to finish before writing. Make sure to call `task_done` on the items you get as well.

Comment: Great idea! Queue is thread-safe and is much nicer than list.append(data)

Comment: I added the call to `task_done` as suggested by darvids0n. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say store a list of lists (`bool`, `str`), where `bool` is whether the function has finished running and `str` is the output. Each function locks the list with a mutex to append output (or if you don't care about thread safety omit this). Then, have a simple polling loop checking if all the `bool` values are `True`, and if so then do your `save_to_disk` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to implement a class (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156564/1129194)) that uses `threading.Lock()`. This has the advantage of being able to wait on the `ItemStore`, and save_to_disk can use `getAll`, rather than polling the queue. (More efficient for large data sets?)

This is particularly suited to writing at a set time interval (ie every 30 seconds), rather than once per second.

```
class ItemStore(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.items = []

    def add(self, item):
        with self.lock:
            self.items.append(item)

    def getAll(self):
        with self.lock:
            items, self.items = self.items, []
        return items
```